# How to quickly traverse a very large table in Iceberg

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-iceberg

I have a question about a query big table.

We have a Hive table with a total of 3.6 million records and 120 fields per record. and we want to transfer all the records in this table to other databases, such as pg, kafka, etc.

Currently we do like this:

````
 Dataset<Row> dataset = connection.client.read().format("iceberg").load("default.table");
// here will  stuck for a very long time
dataset.foreachPartition(par ->{
    par.forEachRemaining(row ->{
       ```
    });
});
````

but it can get stuck for a long time in the foreach process.

and I tried the following method, the process does not stay stuck for long, but the traversal speed is very slow, the traverse efficiency is about 50 records/second.

````
HiveCatalog hiveCatalog = createHiveCatalog(props);
Table table = hiveCatalog.loadTable(TableIdentifier.of("default.table"));
CloseableIterable<Record> records = IcebergGenerics.read(table) .build();
records.forEach( record ->{
    ```
});
````

Neither of these two ways can meet our needs. Does my code need to be modified?

Comment: This progress is running on spark local mode. I think it takes a long time to generate Spark tasks, and eventually it would generate over 10,000 tasks.

Comment: Are you writing the data row by row? This will be much slower than writing in batches, in most target databases.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to reading row by row, here is another idea.

If your target database can import files directly, try retrieving files from Iceberg and importing them directly to the database.

Example code is as follows:

```
   Iterable<DataFile> files = FindFiles.in(table)
        .inPartition(table.spec(), StaticDataTask.Row.of(1))
        .inPartition(table.spec(), StaticDataTask.Row.of(2))
        .collect();
```

You can get the file path and Format from the DataFile.